# Set display to a higher resolution than 720p?

Tags: 14.10, intel

buen dia comunidad.
Les quisiera preguntar si existe alguna manera de modificar mi resolucion actual que es de 1366x768 por alguna superior como 1600x900 o 1920x1680. Cabe decir que 1366x768 es la maxima resolucion soportada por mi monitor.

Intel Core i7 segunda generacion a 2.00GHz

Mi driver de video es:
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family 
Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Mi sistema es Ubuntu 14.10 x64

---

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?source=osdd#auto/en/buen%20dia%20comunidad.%0ALes%20quisiera%20preguntar%20si%20existe%20alguna%20manera%20de%20modificar%20mi%20resolucion%20actual%20que%20es%20de%201366x768%20por%20alguna%20superior%20como%201600x900%20o%201920x1680.%20Cabe%20decir%20que%201366x768%20es%20la%20maxima%20resolucion%20soportada%20por%20mi%20monitor.%0A%0AIntel%20Core%20i7%20segunda%20generacion%20a%202.00GHz%0A%0AMi%20driver%20de%20video%20es%3A%0AVGA%20compatible%20controller%3A%20Intel%20Corporation%202nd%20Generation%20Core%20Processor%20Family%20%0AIntegrated%20Graphics%20Controller%20(rev%2009)%0A%0AMi%20sistema%20es%20Ubuntu%2014.10%20x64):

good day community.
We would ask if there is any way to modify my current resolution which is 1366x768 by some superior as 1920x1680 or 1600x900. We can say that 1366x768 is the maximum resolution supported by my monitor.

Intel Core i7 second generation to 2.00GHz

My video driver is:
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family
Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

My system is Ubuntu 14.10 x64

---

Thank you very much!
Added the 1600x900 resolution to match the 16:9 ratio of my laptop screen.
Some fonts seems a little blurry, is there a way to apply a font aliasing or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si, claro.

The following is a script that works for *LVDS1* (typicaly laptops).  I don't know if it works on other modes.  I have not tested it.

Execute `xrandr --prop | grep connected` to see which mode you use.  If LVDS1 is *connected* You could use the script. and it doesn't "overdrive" the hardware.

Have a user directory for scripts, e.g., `mkdir ~/bin`

Open an empty file, `gedit ~/bin/nxrez`

Paste in the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Marc Brumlik, Tailored Software Inc, tsi-inc@comcast.net
# Wed Jan  2 05:23:54 CST 2013

# newrez v 1.0
# use xrandr to scale the display to a new resolution
# rewriten to handle mouse boundaries when scaled
# this requires setting a new resolution to the unused VGA1 device
# then scaling that for B display on the LVDS1 device
# modified by Moe to include zenity.

umask 000

# resolution can optionally be specified on command line
newrez=$1

# we MUST be running xrandr 1.3 or higher
if xrandr -v | grep "RandR version 1.[012]"
   then   zenity --info --title="XRandR version is too old" --text="You must be running Xrandr
version 1.3 or newer!
Time to upgrade your system  :-)"
      exit 0
fi

# find the currently connected devices, make a list
devices=`xrandr -q | grep connected | grep -v disconnected | cut -d"(" -f1`

# there MUST be a "connected" LVDS1 and a "disconnected" VGA1
current=`xrandr -q`

if echo "$current" | grep "LVDS1 connected" >/dev/null
   then   : OK
   else   zenity --info --title="PROBLEM" --text="Current display must be LVDS1"; exit 0
fi
if echo "$current" | grep "VGA1 disconnected" >/dev/null
   then   : OK
   else   zenity --info --title="IMPORTANT" --text="The VGA1 display resolution may be affected by this change"
fi

default=`echo "$current" | grep -A 1 "^LVDS1" | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'`
H=`echo $default | cut -d'x' -f1`
V=`echo $default | cut -d'x' -f2`
HZ=`echo $default | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '[*+]'`

# echo DEFAULT: $default $H $V

  title="Resolutions"
  text="Default Resolution: $default"


if [ -z "$newrez" ]
   then   while true
      do
         newrez=$(zenity --title="$title" --list \
            --height=250 --width 250 --text="$text" \
            --radiolist --column="X" --hide-column=2 --column="Resolution" --column="Screen Size" \
            FALSE    default     "1440 X 900 --- 100%" \
            FALSE   1800x1125    "1800 X 1125 -- 125%" \
            TRUE   2016x1260     "2016 X 1260 -- 140%" \
            FALSE   2304x1440    "2304 x 1440 -- 160%" )
#           additional settings tailored to your machine can be added here
#           changing the above ")" to a "\"
#           with the last one in the list ending with ")"
#           For example:
#           FALSE   1440x900    "1440 X 900 -- 140%" \
#           FALSE   4096x2400   "4096 X 2400 Maximum" )
         case $newrez in
            default|[0-9]*x[0-9]*)   break ;;
         esac
            exit 0
      done
fi

case $newrez in
   default)   xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --output LVDS1 --auto
         xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode $default --scale 1x1
         exit 0 ;;
esac

newH=`echo $newrez | cut -d'x' -f1`
newV=`echo $newrez | cut -d'x' -f2`
modeline=`cvt $newH $newV $HZ | grep Modeline`
newmode=`echo "$modeline" | sed 's/^.*"//'`
cvtrez=`echo "$modeline" | sed -e 's/_.*//' -e 's/^.*"//'`

if [ "$newrez" != "$cvtrez" ]
   then   newrez=$cvtrez
      newH=`echo $newrez | cut -d'x' -f1`
      newV=`echo $newrez | cut -d'x' -f2`
fi

scaleH=`echo -e "scale=10\n$newH / $H\nquit" | bc`
scaleV=`echo -e "scale=10\n$newV / $V\nquit" | bc`

if echo "$current" | grep -A 100 "^VGA1" | grep $newrez >/dev/null
   then   : already there
   else   xrandr --newmode "$newrez" $newmode
      xrandr --addmode VGA1 $newrez
fi

if xrandr --output VGA1 --mode $newrez --output LVDS1 --fb $newrez --scale $scaleH"x"$scaleV 2>&1 | tee -a /tmp/xrandr.err
   then   : success
   else   zenity --info --title="Xrandr produced this error" --text="`cat /tmp/xrandr.err`"

The problem could be that Your video driver
does not support xrandr version 1.3
      rm -f /tmp/xrandr.err
fi
```

Save and make the script executable, `chmod +x ~/bin/nxrez`

You can even create a menu entry `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/alilbigger.desktop`, or put a copy on your decktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=A little bigger screen
Comment=Change screen resolution for a large/smaller desktop
Exec= ./bin/nxrez
Icon=preferences-desktop-theme.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Settings;
```

Save and click away.

Comment: That is one long script. What does it do? Is it yours?

Comment: @muru "# Marc Brumlik, Tailored Software Inc, tsi-inc@comcast.net" so no :D

Comment: @Rinzwind that's my guess as well. Wondering why OP has not given a link to the source.

Comment: Here is the source: http://gnomefiles.org/content/show.php/newrez+-+Increase+Screen+Rez+For+Netbook?content=134686

Comment: Sorry, here's the link from my source [email](file:///home/nodak/Mail/inbox/1675). I tried the script and it worked. Attribution and description are at the top. I guess it's renamed because it was modified from Mark Brumlik's original. The desktop file is trivial

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to [set higher resolution with `xrandr`](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=78330) than what your monitor supports but your monitor would have no way of displaying it and would display nothing at all. You need a monitor that can display higher resolution if you also want to see it.